# foreach checkboxes assign value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, checkbox

Currently, I have a Table, to facilitate appointment booking, based on the data from the Dataset.

The table columns is based on the number of Table Data from [Object] and rows is from 9am to 9pm, 1 row per hour.

For each rows, I've added checkbox : for eg: if users checked checkboxes from 2-6, then I will be blocking off the timeslots

```
foreach (DataRow objectrow in ds.Tables["Object"].Rows)
{
    myTableCell = new TableCell();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    myTableCell.Controls.Add(cb);
    myTableRow.Cells.Add(myTableCell);
}
```

However, I have problems assigning the id of the checkboxes and I'm confused on how to achieving it due to multiple objects in the database.

To test the codes, I've assigned Label.Text to check whether any checkboxes is selected.
I've tried looping through foreach(rows) then (cell) then (Control) but still wasn't able to get it to work.

Appreciate any feedback as I'm new at programming

Comment: why dont't you consume objectrow in your loop?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander sorry, consume objectrow in the loop meaning?

Comment: objectrow should contain the data you want to assign in your loop, but the variable is unused

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Can you please elaborate more on what u want to achieve ? you want to assign unique id from database to each dynamic checkbox ?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander im going to try, see whether im able to implement it

Comment: @MayurPatel I need to check whether the checkbox isSelected. If it is, check the value- for eg: 6PM-under Object1 Column. If checked, then i need to store it in the database, DateTime - varDateTime, followed by Object1 ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code and my understanding on your question you are creating `checkbox` and adding it dynamically to `TableCell`.

So now if you want to check status of `checkbox` which is dynamically created you have to assign unique ID to each `checkbox` which can be done with following code.

Assuming that your table on which you are looping have some unique column assume that column name is `id`.

```
foreach (DataRow objectrow in ds.Tables["Object"].Rows)
{
    myTableCell = new TableCell();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    //Add unique id to each checkbox...
    cb.Attributes.Add("id",objectrow["id"].ToString());
    myTableCell.Controls.Add(cb);
    myTableRow.Cells.Add(myTableCell);
}
```

So now it will assign unique id to each CheckBox from your table and you can check it's status from this ID and do your work for that..

This is what my understanding if its my mis-understanding let me know.

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your help! It helped me to be able to add attributes successfully. I've added cb.Attributes as objectID and cb.InputAttributes as rowID. Not sure whether there will be any conflict though